# Is there any symbolic execution tools in llvm?

Tags: pointers, llvm, llvm-ir, symbolic-execution

I want to do points-to anlysis in llvm IR. I want it to be path sensitive, which means that when I print out the result, I need append the condition for the "May" Points-to.

I plan to using symbolic execution to achieve this goal.

Are there any tools in llvm, or stand-alone tools to solve the symbolic equation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some pointers to get you started:

1. The [Scalar Evolution LLVM module](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2009-10/ScalarEvolutionAndLoopOptimization.pdf) is basically symbolic execution of arithmetic expressions (and taking loops into consideration).
2. [Klee](http://ccadar.github.io/klee/) is a full symbolic execution VM for LLVM IR.